# Plugin not firing on status change of Order

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Anyone know of any reason a plugin registered for `SetState` and `SetStateDynamicEntity` isn't firing on `salesorder`?  If I register for `Update` against statecode it fires correctly.

I've tried registering in all different stages in the pipeline, iisreset, unregister/register without success.  Also checked it fires correctly for these messages against a different entity, which it does.

Checked the spreadsheet in the SDK and they're valid messages for `salesorder`.  I know that an `orderclose` activity is also created "under the hood" so wasn't sure if there was something else at play here in respect of the whole order proces?

In this instance I can achieve what I want by registering the `Update` message against the statecode attribute.  However, I'd like to understand the reason for this behaviour.

Comment: which exact status change you are trying to catch?

Comment: @GuidoPreite Specifically Fulfill/Complete, but I've executed against all derivatives of Fulfill and Cancel without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried with a simple plugin (just throw an `InvalidPluginExecutionException`) and actually the plugin is not fired if registered on `SetState` or `SetStateDynamicEntity`.

Looking at MSDN I found this example:

[Sample: Fulfill a Sales Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547399.aspx)

It uses the message `FulfillSalesOrderRequest` in this way:

```cs
// Close the sales order with a status of Complete
int newStatus = (int)salesorder_statuscode.Complete;
var request = new FulfillSalesOrderRequest
{
    OrderClose = new OrderClose
    {
        SalesOrderId = new EntityReference 
            { LogicalName = SalesOrder.EntityLogicalName, Id = _salesOrderId.Value }

    },
    Status = new OptionSetValue(newStatus)
};
```

and inside the MSDN for the FulfillSalesOrderRequest Class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.fulfillsalesorderrequest.aspx

is written:

> **Privileges and Access Rights** 
> To perform this action, the caller must
>   have privileges on the OrderClose entity and access rights on the
>   records specified in the OrderClose property.
> For a complete list of
>   required privileges, see FulfillSalesOrder Privileges.

After I registered my plugin on `Create` step for `OrderClose` entity (`Pre-operation` stage) and it works (throwing me the exception) when I try to fulfill an order.

Looks like this is the suggested way (at least from MSDN) to intercept the fulfill of an order.

Comment: Thanks.  Your findings appear to align with my understanding and more importantly that I wasn't missing something obvious.  I'm still puzzled by the spreadsheet in the SDK saying the SetState messages are valid for salesorder.  If nobody else comes in with further info on SetState I'll mark accepted.